# PowerShell App Deployment Toolkit - Show logoff box?

Tags: powershell, deployment, sccm

I am trying to use the PSAPPDelpoymenttoolkit. Is there a way I can show a popup to the user that they need to logoff? And when that happens execute the installation code I need?
Basically I need to rename a folder that is in use when a user is logged on. So I want them to be prompted to logoff and then have my code rename the folder. Is this possible?

https://psappdeploytoolkit.com/

Something like this would log them off but how can I show a dialog box?

```
Execute-ProcessAsUser -Path “$($envWinDir)\System32\logoff.exe” -RunLevel LeastPrivilege
```

Comment: While the below answer is correct in how to provide the user with a messagebox, please keep in mind that if you deploy a program via sccm that logs the user off this will terminate the sccm program. So what you have to do is, have the logoff as last action in the script, do not wait for logoff. Have a second program that runs only when no user is logged on that always runs the popup program first and have this rename the folder. Disclaimer: this would be sccm standard practice it might be different with psappdeploytoolkit I don't know whether they have a workaround for the logoff problematic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below code, user gets a pop-up. They can click 'OK' or 'Cancel'. If cancel they get another popup that says they clicked cancel. If they click OK then your command will execute. Powershell does not natively have this ability, we had to tap into .net for this.

```
$oReturn=[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("In order to xyz, you must log off your workstation. Please click ok to logoff.","Logoff Required",[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OKCancel)

if($oReturn -eq 1){
    Execute-ProcessAsUser -Path “$($envWinDir)\System32\logoff.exe” -RunLevel LeastPrivilege
}
else{
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("You have chosen not to log out.","Logoff Canceled",[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK)
}
```